# Cabbage : Are these cabbages different

Tags: identification, cabbage

Please find attached below the images of cabbages that I have with me. Is the cabbages different or it has grown differently based on the place.

The one with three cabbage plants is what i am growing(at Coimbatore, India) and the one with a single plant is grown by my one of the relatives(at Bangalore, India).

Kindly help in identifying it.

[image: Three cabbages- Mine]

[image: Relative's cabbage]

Comment: Cabbages is a plant species ( *Brassica oleracea* ), with many many varieties and cultivars. This is similar to many garden vegetables. So environment could change it, but mostly, pollen easily mix with other varieties, so seeds are often not 100% of a single variety. Variability is the norm (in cultivated plants).

Comment: As often with these types of vegetable- seeds are only really supplied by seed companies, and there are hundreds of varieties available. I wouldn't grow all one type anyway, can cause problems with pests etc build up. succession throughout the year can done with several different varieties- I would grow something different every time and experiment with every new crop. Would also be helpful if one kept records at home too.